# How do we Obtain the Coordinates of Alphabet which is drawn on iPhone Screen

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios5, uigesturerecognizer

I Want to implement Alphabet Recognition using $1 Uni-stroke Recognizer and $N Multi-stroke Recognizer. In those Recognizers they provide Coordinates for Alphabets "V","D","X","T".

```
"V" Coordinates in Uni-Stroke recognizer are:
(89,164),(90,162),(92,162),(94,164),(95,166),(96,169),(97,171),(99,175),(101,178),
(103,182),(106,189),(108,194),(111,199),(114,204),(117,209),(119,214),(122,218),
(124,222),(126,225),(128,228),(130,229),(133,233),(134,236),(136,239),(138,240),
(139,242),(140,244),(142,242),(142,240),(142,237),(143,235),(143,233),(145,229),
(146,226),(148,217),(149,208),(149,205),(151,196),(151,193),(153,182),(155,172),
(157,165),(159,160),(162,155),(164,150),(165,148),(166,146);

"V" Coordinates in Multi-Stroke recognizer are:
(76,24),(133,139),(183,23);
```

How they Define these Coordinates and How Can i get the Coordinates for the Remaining Alphabets?

Comment: Is there a problem with the existing https://github.com/chrismiles/CMUnistrokeGestureRecognizer?

Comment: No, it's Working. in that one they implemented for Some Shapes. I Want to implement this for Alphabets. How Can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is an exercise for the reader (or something to license; see [Phatware](http://www.phatware.com/index.php?q=page/writepadsdk/ios) for example). I don't believe anyone has put together a fully trained engine and then given it away for free. You need to do a lot of handwriting and tweak the values. You can find an [example JavaScript trainer](http://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/) at the $1 Recognizer site (see the dollar.js code and AddGesture()).

Personally, I would recommend licensing this kind of thing unless this is the whole point of your product.